# How to create inactive user account in django-registration by using admin action without user form

Tags: django, django-registration

I'm new to Python and Django and am trying to develop a 3 step activation/registration system.

**Step 1:** Register with an email address, first and last names for validation.

**Step 2:** Once validated, create a new user record with an activation key to be emailed and the email address as the record user name.

**Step 3:** Activate account.

---

I have created an application that takes care of step 1, and I have been able to combine django-registration and the django custom user model to deal with steps 2 and 3.

This all works with a manual link between steps 1 and 2 via the built in admin facility.  However, I would like to have an admin action that can select all the validated users from step 1 and use the records to automatically process step 2 without having to use a form for each one.

I believe I should be able to call the RegistrationManager create_inactive_user method to do this. My problem is that with limited Python/Django knowledge I am struggling to call this method.

Actually I think I am calling it OK but am hitting an error with the step 1 application model. This model uses the normalize_email utility from BaseManager and works when used directly within that application, but when I use create_inactive_user I get an error:
TypeError at /admin/simple_reg/emailreg/
'NoneType' object is not callable

I assume that there is something that I am not including. The following is the relevant detail from my admin.py file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

from simple_reg.models import EmailReg       # Initial step 1 registration model
from userinfo.models import UserManager      # Step 2 and 3 custom user model
from registration.models import RegistrationManager


class EmailRegAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
...
    def create_user_record(self, request, queryset):
        # Generate new User records from validated email contacts
        count = 0
        validated = len(queryset)
        for contact in queryset:
            pword = 'randomletters'
            try:
                existing = get_user_model().objects.filter(email__exact=contact.email)
                if existing.exists():
                    print "A user with the email address of %s already exists." % (contact.email)
                else:
                    RegistrationManager().create_inactive_user(contact.first_name,
                                           contact.last_name, contact.email, pword, site)
                        count = count + 1
                except:
                    print "User %s was not created" % (contact.email)

        self.message_user(request, "Of %s validations, %s user accounts have been created." % (validated, count))

create_user_record.short_description = "Generate new User records on selected contacts"
```

I am sure it is something quite simple, so hopefully someone will be able to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer myself finally.

I should have been calling RegistrationProfile, not RegistrationManager.

I knew it was something simple!

Answer (score 0):

May be the simplest way can be to create your own User model and define a field like is_active() of boolean type.

Comment: Not sure how that would help, so I probably didn't explain the problem well enough. I already have a custom user model on the main records being used with django-registration. What I wanted was a way of creating these records in auto/batch mode, rather than using the form.